# HttpClient Angular 4.4.3 CSRF and CORS

Tags: angular, cross-domain, csrf

How is a CORS setup supposed to work with Angular's XSRF protection?  Absolute URLs are just ignored, but I need XSRF to work with absolute URLs too. Shouldn't this be configurable with `HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions()`? It seems like an oversight in the code.

Specifically, I see this in the Angular code:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xsrf.ts#L77-L84

```
// Skip both non-mutating requests and absolute URLs.
// Non-mutating requests don't require a token, and absolute URLs require special handling
// anyway as the cookie set
// on our origin is not the same as the token expected by another origin.
if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD' || lcUrl.startsWith('http://') ||
    lcUrl.startsWith('https://')) {
  return next.handle(req);
}
```

Comment: I think that any XHR request can't access a cookie from a different domain, since the method for CSRF in angular is to read a cookie, it must be in the same domain. even if it's javascript readable, xhr.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie") is not readable, so I'm not sure how this can work